# Dont show the $stateParams value in the link

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to access the `$stateParams` value on my controller but I dont want to show the value on the links. Is this possible?

HTML

```
<a ui-sref="baba.watch({name: card.name, aktar: {chapter:card.chapter, link:card.link}})">
```

Javascript

```
.state('baba.series', {
url: "/series/:name/:aktar",
templateUrl: "states/baba.series.html",
controller: "nbgCtrl"
});

.controller('nbgCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
            $scope.milo = $stateParams.aktar.link;
            console.log($scope.milo);
```

I am getting undefined.
Links should be look like `/series/Naruto/345`. Show the chapter value do not show the link value.

Edit: Output of $stateParams:

```
isim:"Naruto",
aktar:"[object Object]"
```

Comment: What's the output of `$stateParams` ? Your `$stateParams` should look like `{ isim: 'Naruto', aktar: '345' }` so the `$stateParams.aktar.link` is naturally `undefined` because there's no `link` property

Comment: @taguenizy I add the output to my post. So basically I want to use `link` value in the `aktar` param. But dont want to show up at the links. `chapter` value should be appear on the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set data on the state, it will not be displayed on the URL when the state loads.

```
.state('baba.series', {
  url: "/series",
  templateUrl: "states/baba.series.html",
  controller: "nbgCtrl",
  data: {
    link: 'some value',
    isim: 'Value', 
    aktar: 'Value'
  }
});
```

You can now retrieve the values from your controller

```
.controller('nbgCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.milo = $state.data.link;
  $scope.isim = $state.data.isim;
  $scope.aktar = $state.data.aktar;
  console.log($scope.milo);
}
```

Comment: But how can i get the value for the `link` in state. Value for link param is accessable from parent state.

Comment: But how can i get the value for the link in that state. Value for link param is accessable from parent state.

Answer (score 0):

Define your state URL like below

`url: "/series"`

You won't get in URL, At the same time you can also get the value/data in $stateParams